# How can I deploy Django, FCGI or otherwise, to an old SunOS Apache server?

Tags: apache-2.2, django, sunos, deployment

I have a somewhat stodgy Apache server, running under SunOS, and I would like an appropriate way to deploy a Django application based at /shop/ or some other URL. The server seems set up to allow FastCGI in some form; there is an /fcgi-bin/ directory with one entry.

Apache does not recognize the FastCGIExternalServer directive, and I would need to be told how to have it load additional modules.

Is there a way I can leverage the /fcgi-bin/ directory and httpd.conf so that requests for /shop/foo/ are serviced by Django?

Answer (score 0):

"SunOS" covers a *whole* lot of ground. If it is old enough version of Solaris, and you cannot update it for some reason, I would recommend building a new set of apache binaries with support for the modules that you need, either FastCGI or mod_wsgi.

Comment: Thank you. What are the configuration options I should specify for both mod_wsgi support and FastCGI support?

Comment: I've compiled mod_wsgi, and it doesn't seem to have generated a .so. Is there one or more of the .la, .lo, or .slo extensions that I can put with Apache .so's?